# JavaScript to Python: simplify encoding of HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, encode

I have a JavaScript module that needs to encode an HTML string that includes entities, and that needs to be correctly received in a Python 2.7 module.

The following works for every example I've tried:

- On the sending side in JavaScript:

  `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(*html-string*)))`
- On the receiving side in Python 2.7:

  `base64.b64decode(self.request.get(u'*parameter-name*'))`

But that's a lot of conversions.

I've tried many other approaches. For example, I of course tried it without `unescape(encodeURIComponent(...))`, and I've tried replacing `unescape` (which is deprecated) with `decodeURI` and with `decodeURIComponent`. None of those attempts worked.

I also tried sending with `encodeURIComponent()` and receiving with `urllib.unquote()`, which didn't crash and retained all my content, but inserted some garbage characters.

Any suggestion for a simpler approach than the one I ended up with would be appreciated.

*NOTE: I don't know whether it's relevant, but the JavaScript module is in an Ionic/AngularJS project and the parameter is being serialized with `$httpParamSerializerJQLike`. Meanwhile, the Python 2.7 module is in a GAE application and the request is being handled by `webapp2`.*

Comment: do you need to send it as an HTML string or could you send it as json which can, relatively easily, be converted into a python dictionary?

Comment: The data actually is an HTML string. It's created in an HTML editor on the sending side, and will be displayed as part of an HTML page in a browser on the receiving side.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` should encode the string to be suitable to send as part of an URI, therefore, you shouldn't need to convert it to base 64, as long as you can decode URIs in Python.

Comment: Too bad those garbage characters I mentioned got inserted.

Comment: @Lindsay can you provide an example of the source text that you have trouble with? It might just be an encoding issue (such as characters encoded as UTF-8 in the source and not correctly decoded in Python)

Comment: <div>
<p>Here&#39;s a table:</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><span style="color:#FF0000;">This is red.</span></td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: lightblue;">This has a blue background.</td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td><u>This is underlined.</u></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<p> </p>
</div>

Comment: And with the garbage characters: <div>
<p>Here&#39;s a table:</p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><span style="color:#FF0000;">This is red.</span></td>
   <td>&Acirc; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color: lightblue;">This has a blue background.</td>
   <td>&Acirc; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&Acirc; </td>
   <td><u>This is underlined.</u></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<p>&Acirc; </p>
</div> See those `&Acirc;` that got inserted?  :0(

Comment: That definitely looks like an encoding issue. I don't get the `&Acirc;`s when I use `urllib.unquote()` on the URI-encoded string. What does your URI-encoded string look like?

Comment: This seems like a charset conversion issue to me - you might need to add .decode('ISO-8859-1') (or whatever your encoding is) before you feed the input to urllib.unquote().

Comment: Too long to send all of it, but ends like this: This%20is%20underlined.%3C%2Fu%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%09%09%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%09%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%C2%A0%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A

Comment: What does yours look like, @rid, starting at "This%20is%20underlined..."?

Comment: @le_m I guess I should know this but I don't. How do I determine what my encoding is, that is, what parameter to use for `.decode()`?

Comment: What encoding does your HTML document use from which you send your XMLHttpRequests to your server?

Comment: @le_m I'm sorry, I'm don't know how to find out. Is it this, perhaps: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Next step would be to analyze your request via developer console (press F12 -> Network tab) and look for your ajax request. Have a look at the request parameters. If you send data via POST, look for the "Content-Type" request header. Is everything looking good?

Comment: In my original post, I supplied both ends of a working version. I've tried a lot of other things, both before I sent the post and since receiving suggestions from the commenters above. I greatly appreciate your efforts to help, but I guess I'll stick with what I've got unless someone would like to supply an actual alternate working version of the requirement, again for both ends. Thanks.